# Retrieve position from binary number ordered by number of ones

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binary

I have binary numbers of length *s*.
They are ordered by numbers of ones, and they can have at most *j* zeros.

That is: first are ordered all numbers containing (s; 0) possible subsets of s numbers, next are all numbers containing (s; 1) possible subsets of s numbers.....last are all (s; j) possible subsets of s numbers.

(s; j) is binomial coefficient s!/(j!(s-j)!)

For s = 4 and j = 2, problem looks like this:
1111
1110
1101
1011
0111
1100
1010
0110
1001
0101
0011

**Problem**: how can I given the binary representation get the position?
1111 should give me position 0, 1110 should be assigned with position 1, and so on.

Please, I would appreciate any kind of help. Thank you!

Comment: How are the strings ordered within the group that has the same number of $1$s?  Your example is not lexicographic nor by magnitude of the binary (which would be the same order) because 0110 comes before 1001

Comment: It doesn't matter how are ordered within the group, I can work with any kind of solution, it is just important the order of groups.

Comment: No, which contest? :)

Answer (score 1):

The string of all $1$s occupies ${s\choose 0}=1$ positions, so it is in position $0$.  The strings with one $0$ occupy ${s \choose 1}=s$ positions,  so they run from $1$ to $s$.  The strings with two $0$s occupy ${s \choose 2}=\frac 12s(s-1)$ positions from $s+1$ to $s+\frac 12s(s-1)=\frac 12s(s+1)$ and so on.  You can just count through the number of zeros and add them up.  There is an expression for the [cumulative distribution function of the binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function), but it is not simple.